# cut: stdin: Illegal byte sequence on Mac OS

Tags: macos, grep, cut

I'm new to bash and regex. I'm using the TIC dataset from UIC to practice.
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/tic-mld/

I'm trying to extract the column names from the file **TicDataDescr.txt** which looks something like this:

```
TICEVAL2000.txt: 
Dataset for predictions (4000 customer records). It has the same format as TICDATA2000.txt, only the target is missing. Participants are supposed to return the list of predicted targets only. All datasets are in tab delimited format. 
The meaning of the attributes and attribute values is given below.

TICTGTS2000.txt
Targets for the evaluation set.

DATADICTIONARY

Nr Name Description Domain

1 MOSTYPE Customer Subtype see L0

2 MAANTHUI Number of houses 1 ñ 10

3 MGEMOMV Avg size household 1 ñ 6

4 MGEMLEEF Avg age see L1

5 MOSHOOFD Customer main type see L2

6 MGODRK Roman catholic see L3
...
```

I want to take only the second column of the description:

```
MOSTYPE
MAANTHUI
MGEMOMV
MGEMLEEF
MOSHOOFD
MGODRK
...
```

I'm trying with to do it with the following code:

```
egrep "^[0-9]+\s[A-Z][A-Z]+" TicDataDescr.txt | cut -d' ' -f2
```

But I'm encountering the following error:

```
MOSTYPE
cut: stdin: Illegal byte sequence
```

I've tried converting the file using dos2unix

```
dos2unix TicDataDescr.txt
```

but i still get the same error.
Why am I running into such error? Also, is there a way around it using regex? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Try `export LC_ALL=C` before using `cut`

Comment: The input file uses something other than UTF-8 character encoding, so when `cut` tries to parse it as UTF-8, it gets errors. It *also* uses DOS/Windows line endings, so `dos2unix` is fixing *that* problem... but that's not the problem that's causing the error. To fix the character problem properly, you need to figure out what character encoding the file uses, and either process it using that encoding, or convert it to UTF-8.